# Importance of dependencies in a fresh Ionic app

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework

I am working on a project and plan to use Ionic to make the mobile app. I started by using

```
ionic start project-name tabs --type=react --capacitor
```

and I got 27 vulnerabilities, out of which 18 high and one critical. I have tried using "npm audit fix" and whatever else they recommended but none of that fixed anything. Is this something I should be worried about? I am not sure which of those deprecated libraries I will need over the course of the project so doing it manually seems very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I do four things when I start a project:

1. I run https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates
   If you install this package, you will be able to run `ncu` and get a list of packages which need updating. You can also run `ncu -u` to automatically edit the pacakage.json for you.
2. I also lock my dependencies. Meaning, I remove all '~' and '^' values from my package.json. Nothing more frustrating than to have a project suddenly stop working because a '^' pushed you to a later version which breaks something.
3. Run `npm i` in order to install the latest from package.
4. Spend the next day or so fixing the various build and linting errors, but that's outside the scope of this question.